# Does OAuth 2.0 refresh token expires at all?

Tags: oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, access-token

I need to understand if a refresh token from OAuth 2.0 for Google data expires or not if unused for more than 6 months?

At many places it is called out that it doesn't expire and at some places it is said that it will expire if unused for 6 months.

For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953983/do-google-refresh-token-expire), the accepted answer says that it never expires but one of the comments suggest that it can expire if unused for 6 months.

[This Google doc](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh) calls out that refresh token will never expire while [this doc](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#expiration) says it can expire if not used for 6 months.

Although I am using a safety check for the cases where refresh token is expired due to any reason, but still want to make sure I understand the behavior correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct the two pages [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) and [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#expiration) don't have the same information.

Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs is correct.

> You should write your code to anticipate the possibility that a
> granted token might no longer work. A token might stop working for one
> of these reasons:
>
> - The user has revoked access.
> - The token has not
>   been used for six months.
> - The user account has exceeded a certain
>   number of token requests.
>
> There is currently a 25-token limit per Google user account. If a user
> account has 25 valid tokens, the next authentication request succeeds,
> but quietly invalidates the oldest outstanding token without any
> user-visible warning.
>
> If you need to authorize multiple programs, machines, or devices, one
> workaround is to limit the number of clients that you authorize per
> user account to 15 or 20. If you are a Google Apps admin, you can
> create additional admin users and use them to authorize some of the
> clients.

A refresh token that hasn't been used for 6 months will expire.

I have sent in a bug report on the first URL.  Google should clear up the discrepancy the next time they go though the documents.