# Doorkeeper Refresh Tokens Not Expiring on Reuse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, doorkeeper

I'm using Doorkeeper 5.2.1 and Ive consulted the [Doorkeeper docs on refresh tokens](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Enable-Refresh-Token-Credentials#flow) and have read through several GitHub issues and pull requests related to refresh tokens, notably [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/739) and [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/pull/578).

From what I gather from these conversations and from reading the spec (and [documents and posts referencing the spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40587918/931934), the following statements are true:

- Refresh tokens are long lived (as opposed to access tokens, which typically expire after a relatively short TTL)
- An authorization server MAY implement revocation
- Doorkeeper implements refresh token revocation *on some basis* (though I'm not clear what, keep reading)

I'm confused, though, based on [this pull request](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/pull/578), which implements refresh token expiry after an "access token created with that refresh token is successfully used once." How would Doorkeeper know if I've made an API request with that access token successfully? It's my API that works out the authorization logic based on that access token. Doorkeeper is agnostic to my API requests being successful or not. However, I've interpreted that to mean that if the `resource_owner_authenticator` block returns a user, that could constitute successful use. Yet I have not found that that expires a refresh token successfully. (See my spec below.)

It also appears from reading [this spec file](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/master/spec/lib/oauth/refresh_token_request_spec.rb#L48-L50) that if you successfully use a refresh token, it revokes the previous refresh tokens, which would make sense.

I'm trying to work all this out in my spec file, though, and I'm running into an issue where it doesn't appear that a refresh token is revoked, even when it's used multiple times, or it ("refresh token A") is reused *after* the refresh token ("token B") that returns with the access token that refresh token A is used to generate, is also used. My spec file will make this clearer:

```
describe 'OAuth flow' do
  # ...
  describe 'refresh tokens' do

    # ...
    context 'when attempting reuse of a refresh token' do
      before do
        redirect_uri = 'https://localhost:3002'

        # ivars necessary brecause plaintext tokens/secrets are only available upon creation of the object
        @client = Doorkeeper::Application.create(name: 'foo', uid: 'bar', redirect_uri: redirect_uri, scopes: 'project_index')
        @secret = @client.plaintext_secret
        @grant = Doorkeeper::AccessGrant.create(resource_owner_id: user.id, organization_id: org.id, application_id: @client.id, scopes: 'project_index', expires_in: 600, redirect_uri: redirect_uri)
        @code = @grant.plaintext_token
      end

      it 'revokes the initial refresh token' do
        # Get an initial access token and refresh token
        post "/oauth/token?client_id=#{@client.uid}&client_secret=#{@secret}&code=#{@code}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=#{@client.redirect_uri}&scope=project_index"
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)

        # Use refresh token to get a new access token
        previous_refresh_token = JSON.parse(response.body)['refresh_token']

        post "/oauth/token?client_id=#{@client.uid}&client_secret=#{@secret}&code=#{@code}&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=#{previous_refresh_token}&redirect_uri=#{@client.redirect_uri}&scope=project_index"
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)
        json_body = JSON.parse(response.body)
        new_access_token = json_body['access_token']
        new_refresh_token = json_body['refresh_token']

        # Use the new access token successfully
        get "/api/v1/projects?access_token=#{new_access_token}"
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)

        # Use the new refresh token to get yet another access token
        post "/oauth/token?client_id=#{@client.uid}&client_secret=#{@secret}&code=#{@code}&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=#{new_refresh_token}&redirect_uri=#{@client.redirect_uri}&scope=project_index"
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)

        # Attempt reuse of the first refresh token
        post "/oauth/token?client_id=#{@client.uid}&client_secret=#{@secret}&code=#{@code}&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=#{previous_refresh_token}&redirect_uri=#{@client.redirect_uri}&scope=project_index"
        expect(response.status).to eq(400)

        # ^^^ fails, response is 200 and a new access token and refresh token are generated
      end
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

This spec fails on the last assertion, suggesting that for a given refresh token, it is not revoked when the access token it is used to generate is used successfully (contrary to what's stated above), or when the refresh token issued with the refreshed access token is used.

My question is, with Doorkeeper, under what circumstances is a refresh token revoked?

Answer (score 1):

The doorkepeer implement a few flows where the issued token whould be revoked. (I doubt I described all of them, I just remember of those)

- By willingly making a [request](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/API-endpoint-descriptions-and-examples#post---oauthrevoke) to revoke the given token.
- By completing the [refresh token flow](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/API-endpoint-descriptions-and-examples#curl-command-refresh-token-grant), which will revoke the refreshed token. (unless the third flow is enabled)
- By successfully [completing an authentication](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/master/lib/doorkeeper/oauth/token.rb#L15) while having the refresh token flow enabled and by having the column `previous_refresh_token` on your `oauth_access_tokens` table. This column is automatically populated by doorkeeper during the refresh token flow by the current token being refreshed (becoming than the previous token). (this flow has to be enabled on the doorkeeper configuration)
- [Revoking a grant token](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/master/lib/doorkeeper/oauth/authorization_code_request.rb#L33), which is used as a pre auth for the other flows. The grant token is revoked as soon as it is used to get another token (such as client or access tokens)
- On the client credentials flow, by requesting a new token with the reuse access token configuration disabled

Based on all of that I have to say, you're assumption is completly right. The spec you wrote should have revoked the token, which led me to think if that wasn't a bug on doorkeeper. Without seeing your doorkeeper configuration I would be pretty much guessing, but, I found this pull request [#1341](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/pull/1341) from the version [5.3.0](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#530) that is suposed to fix a bug on the revocation of refresh tokens when the `hash_token_secrets` is enabled. If you have `hash_token_secrets` enabled try disabling it or updating the doorkeeper. If none of those is possible try making a monkey patch (as a last resource) and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apologies that I let the bounty expire before I could award it to you. I'll attempt that today and report back.

Comment: Update: that did look promising, because I do have `hash_token_secrets` enabled. I upgraded them gem to 5.3.1, but I'm still seeing that issue. I added a comment to that effect to the issue I filed on the gem repo, so we'll see. I'll keep digging.

Comment: Sorry to hear that it did not workout for you. If you find a solution or understand where the problem is please give me a ring, I'm really curious to know what is happening