# How to handle expired Google refresh code?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api

I want to build a backend application that allow people to CRUD their google calendar's events.

I will use Google Calendar API and OAuth2. I will save user's refresh code into my app's database. So that when users query, I can use the refresh token to refresh the access token and query Google calendar API.

But I wonder is there anyway that I can know user's refresh token is expired. So that I can request users for new authorization.

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Hi ! Don't you deal with the `expires_in` property on the authorization server ? https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-response/

Comment: expires_in here as I know is the expired-time of access token. What I'm confusing is about expiration of refresh token. 
As I read somewhere, refresh token does expired in some special cases. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40555855/does-the-refresh-token-expire-and-if-so-when.
But they didn't talk about how to deal with refresh token's expiration