# Google Drive, service account bulk uploads

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, service-accounts

I have a need to upload around 500GB of data to my google drive. I have bought 1 TB space so space is not an issue. I need to achieve this using drive api. Since I don't want to authorize my script via oauth flow I have decided to use google service account but I came to know that you can only upload 15GB of data using Service account user. Now this is limiting me from using all of my google drive space. I have tried transferring ownership after uploading the file but there is also a limit on number of items shared/transferred in a single day. So question is:

Is there a way to increase the service account drive quota? If not what would be the work around for this. If someone can share a code sample using oauth2 and for how long I can use the refresh token that would be great as I need to run this as a lambda function to sync my s3 bucket to google drive so as little user intervention as possible is desirable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#exponential-backoff). See the Important part (the text shaded in blue) at the bottom part of the document to request additional quota.

> If your application *needs* additional quota, it can be requested in
>   the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) under the *Quotas* tab of a project. Only
>   request additional quota if your application is exceeding the courtesy
>   limit for the Drive API, or if it is exceeding the per-user limit. If
>   exceeding the per-user limit, it is possible that your application
>   code should be optimized to make fewer requests.

From this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953983/do-google-refresh-tokens-expire), the expiration about refresh token was discussed shortly, but you can refer to the documentation for further understanding about [refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration) and some [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#libraries) for Oauth2.