# Why am I getting the error 'Can't generate token. Check your auth options' when using Nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, nodemailer

I see several similar questions regarding normal OATH. However, I decided to try nodemailers new
feature supporting gmail service accounts. I keep getting the same error over and over and no light on how to resolve it. Does anyone have any insight?

Step 1: I set up my service account from my project. Then I downloaded the key.json file.

Step 2: I went to GCP APIs and enabled gmail api for my project. I then verified that my new service account was in the list. (I don't want to post a pic because it contains sensitive information. But I triple checked that it was in the list of service accounts enabled for the gmail api.

Step 3: I wrote a little code.

```
return Promise.resolve()
.then(() => {
      const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          type: 'OAuth2',
          user: <service account email>,
          serviceClient: <service account client>,
          privateKey: <Private key> (including the \n at the end),
        },
      });
})
.then(() => {
        const mailOptions = {
            from: '"Support" support@myapp.com',
            to: targetEmail,
            subject: 'My Subject',
            html: 'My super support email'
          };
          return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
    })
.catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
})
```

I print a nice wonderful error that says

```
Error { Error: Can't generate token. Check your auth options
at SMTPConnection._handleXOauth2Token (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1697:27)
at SMTPConnection.login (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:540:22)
at XOAuth2.generateToken (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/xoauth2/index.js:170:33)
at XOAuth2.getToken (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/xoauth2/index.js:123:18)
at connection.connect (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-transport/index.js:374:32)
at SMTPConnection.once (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:215:17)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
at SMTPConnection.emit (events.js:198:13)
at SMTPConnection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23)
at SMTPConnection._actionEHLO (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1313:14) code: 'EAUTH', command: 'AUTH XOAUTH2' }
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Note: For a little more context. This runs inside of a firebase function.

Comment: Did you find solution for this? Having the same issue

Comment: No. I think it has something about tying the service account to a real mail account. But No luck

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem and I found a solution here:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/multi-purposes-mailing-api-using-nodemailer-gmail-google-oauth-28de49118d77

As described in the tutorial you have to get your refresh token.

In your OAuth credentials in Google APIs Console provide https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ as redirection URI.

Go to https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ page.

In the right corner in settings menu select "Use your own OAuth credentials" and provide your credentials.

Then provide link https://mail.google.com in "Select & authorize APIs" section and click "Authorize APIs" button.

Finally exchange authorization code for tokens.

When you have the refresh token you can pass it in the configuration:

```
{
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        refreshToken: REFRESH_TOKEN,
    },
}
```

According to this answer the google's refresh token will not expire:

[Do Google refresh tokens expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953983/do-google-refresh-tokens-expire#answer-8954103)

Best regards,

Piotr

Comment: It looks like the first link you provided does not exist. was that a mistake?

Comment: Maybe it was a temporary problem. The link should be ok. I have checked it on a different device and it works fine.

Comment: Did they change how it works recently? The old way i was using worked fine like 2 months ago (i dont check the email functionality that often XD), and only now noticed that its not working anymore. Thanks to your answer it works once again though

Answer (score 1):

In my case (and found in nodemailer's documentation), I wasn't pasting the entire private_key including the very beginning `'-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...')`