# google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: Invalid Client

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-ads-api

I am working on a project to let a client authorize their google ads account, and then use those authorized credentials to download data on their behalf. I have a webapp that successfully Authorizes the app to do things on the clients behalf. This generates an access code that I then trade for two credentials, an access token and a refresh token. This refresh token then gets passed to a database, where a separate app attempts to query the googleAds API.
It is my understanding that the Google Oauth engine only needs the refresh token.

I am trying to authorize by use of load_from_dict() or load_from_env() methods of the GoogleAdsClient class. Both yield the same error: `google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_client: Unauthorized', {'error': 'invalid_client', 'error_description': 'Unauthorized'})`

I have verified the developer_token, client_id, and client_secret are all accurate to what is in the API console. I have also verified the refresh_token is being passed correctly to the credential dict.

I am really at a loss on where to go from here. I have read many stack overflow threads with similar titles, and yet I am still stuck at the same place.

Here are some relevant links.

[Google Ads API configuration](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs/python/configuration)

[Google Identity and Server side web apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server)

[Google's example of an API call](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/main/examples/basic_operations/get_campaigns.py)

Relevant code

```
class GoogleAds:

def __init__(self):

    self.scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords']
    self.client_id = os.getenv('GOOGLE_ADS_CLIENT_ID')
    self.client_secret = os.getenv('GOOGLE_ADS_CLIENT_SECRET')
    self.developer_token = os.getenv('GOOGLE_ADS_DEVELOPER_TOKEN')
    self.refresh_token = os.getenv('GOOGLE_ADS_REFRESH_TOKEN')

def authorize(self):

    credentials = {
        "developer_token": self.developer_token,
        "refresh_token": self.refresh_token,
        "client_id": self.client_id,
        "client_secret": self.client_secret,
        "use_proto_plus":"True",
        "grant_type": "refresh_token",
    }
    print(credentials)

    googleads_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_dict(credentials)

    service = googleads_client.get_service("GoogleAdsService")
    request = googleads_client.get_type("SearchGoogleAdsRequest")

    return service, request
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code used to request this refrsh token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up refreshing the Client_Secret in the google API client and that seemed to have gotten me through.

Q: It is outside the scope of this question, but is it possible to get that value from the authorization step?

A: You can get the customer IDs you have access to with the `client.get_service("CustomerService")` method. [There is also a way to get account hierarchy](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/account-management/get-account-hierarchy). I will probably be using (Frankensteining) that to move forward

Comment: Is this an anwser to your question?

Answer (score 1):

`'error': 'invalid_client', 'error_description': 'Unauthorized'` Can be a very hard error to debug.  It can mean a number of things.

Currently it Implies to me that the user has not authorized this client.

First ensure that the refresh token has not expired.  Second ensure that the client id and client secrete used to create the refresh token are the same one that you are using to request a new access token.

## [oauth2#expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

[image]

Comment: [I don't think refresh tokens expire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8954103/16555250).
I have tipple checked the environmental variables for  Client ID and Client Secret are the same. I have also made sure the credential json files are the same.

Comment: Please check my edit refresh tokens can expire.